# Comprobar si un String contiene subcadena especifica

Tags: java, regex

Quiero comprobar si el String cadena contiene un "= " y ese "= " está seguido por un carácter alfanumérico. Por ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "= 'hola"; //patron.matcher(cadena1); devuelve false
String cadena2 = "= hola";  //patron.matcher(cadena2); devuelve true
String cadena3 = "= 1";  //patron.matcher(cadena3); devuelve true
```

El regex que estoy usando es:

```
Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("=\\s[\\w]");
Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(cadena);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión está bien, tienes que llamar el método `find()` del matcher para que busque la primer coincidencia:

```
 if(matcher.find()){
     System.out.printf("encontrado");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes usarlo de esta forma, usando el método find() :

```
  Pattern patron = Pattern.compile("=\\s[\\w]");
  Matcher matcher = patron.matcher(cadena);

  boolean contiene = matcher.find();
  System.out.println("Contiene cadena especifica? "+ contiene);
```